# How to override the build.properties values from console by using ANT targets

Tags: ant

config.properties have values as below:

```
username = system
password = ******
```

build.xml have the default properties values as below:

```
<target name="load-config-properties"
                <property file="${config.properties}"/>
                <echo>Default config params</echo>
                <property name="username" value=""/>
                <property name="password" value=""/>
```

now I dont want to use neither config.properties nor build.xml properties.So I have written some ant input tasks to override the config.properties from console as below

```
 <input message="Enter password for username: "                                                                     addproperty="input.password">
    <handler type="secure"/>
</input>
var name="password" value="${input.password}"/>
```

I am able to provide password from console,but its not overriding the config.properties.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The <input> task has to be executed before you load config.properties.  Within Ant, the first setting of a property wins out, so if your <input> task is executed after config.properties is loaded, it will have no effect.  As @Rao notes, any properties set from the command-line will override any settings in your build file.

Comment: Krishna, did you get chance to try the answer and see if that is helpful?

Comment: Yes @Rao...Its working as expected.but how to hide password? Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to do it, do not choose to use `input`, rather would go for System arguments.

Here is the sample build script:

```
<project name="overrideProperty" basedir="." default="test">  
  <property name="username" value="system"/>
  <target name="test" description="check if the property can be overridden runtime">
    <echo message="Property username's value is ${username}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Regular:** using the same value as defined in the property
If you want to use the same value as defined in the property `username`, call ant build like you do regularly, say:

`ant test`

**Output:**

```
test:
     [echo] Property username's value is system

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

**Overriding Property Value Runtime**  using system argument.
If you want to override the `username` property runtime (without modifying build script, then invoke ant command as below:

`ant test -Dusername="mysystem"`

**Output:**

```
Buildfile: D:\Temp\build2.xml

test:
     [echo] Property username's value is mysystem

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Hope this is helpful.